# MySQL find most recently updated item upon accepted condition

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the following columns:

- id
- id_number
- description
- register_date
- accepted

The id_number is not unique since I can have multiple elements on the same table. I need to find just one element of each id_number with the following criteria:

- If the item has been accepted at least once, I need the item with the newer register_date but only looking at the accepted of its kind.
- If the item hasn't been accepted, then I need the lastest item that has been registered.

For instance, if I have the following data:

```
ID Id_Number    Description             Register_Date         Accepted
==============================================================================
1  TA-001       This is a test           19/02/2015 15:40:35      0
2  TA-004       test                     27/03/2015 12:00:18      1
3  DCMIX-001    test                     01/01/2011 00:00:00      0
4  TA-005       test                     01/01/2010 00:00:00      0
5  TA-001       different description    25/03/2015 11:07:42      1
6  TA-001       not accepted but newer   25/03/2015 11:53:42      0
7  TA-005       test                     27/03/2015 13:10:21      0
```

Will produce this ouptut:

```
ID Id_Number    Description             Register_Date         Accepted
==============================================================================   
2  TA-004       test                    27/03/2015 12:00:18       1
3  DCMIX-001    test                    01/01/2011 00:00:00       0    
5  TA-001       different description   25/03/2015 11:07:42       1
7  TA-005       test                    27/03/2015 13:10:21       0
```

Many thanks for your time.

Comment: What did you tried so far. StackOverflow is not a code-generator service. What is the specific problem with the queries you tried? Please read [ask] in [help] for more information about asking in StackOverflow.

Comment: This is MySQL - so those are not dates!!

Comment: My biggest problem was that I was trying to get the whole result in a single query which so far has been impossible. Seeing the first answer it seems I was wrong in my approach. It is not like I wanted to get free code.

Comment: @Strawberry It is a datetime formatted in spanish like date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT l.*
FROM mytable l                         # 'l' from 'last'
LEFT JOIN mytable n                    # 'n' from 'newer'
    ON l.id_number = n.id_number       # match by in_number
    AND (l.accepted < n.accepted OR    # 'l' < 'n' on (accepted, register_date)
         l.accepted = n.accepted AND l.register_date < n.register_date)
WHERE n.id_number IS NULL              # 'n' (newer) does not exist
```

It selects all the rows you need in a single query and runs faster than the queries that use `GROUP BY`.

#### How it works

The `LEFT JOIN` combines all the rows from the left table (aliased as `l` from `last`) with the matching rows from the right table (aliased as `n` from `newer`). Each row from table `l` is paired with all the rows from table `n` having the same `id_number` and there is also a condition of the `(accepted, register_date)` pair of fields.

Your request is to select for each `id_number` the row having the most recent (the biggest) `register_date`, the rows having `accepted = 1` being preferred to those with `accepted = 0`. This means, for each value of `id_number`, select the row that has the maximum value of the pair `(accepted, register_date)` into the lexicographical order.

That's it, for two pairs `(a, b)` and `(c, d)`:

```
(a, b) < (c, d) if (a < c) or (a = c and b < d)
```

Back to the query, the condition of the pair `(accepted, register_date)` of `l` being less than the same pair of `n` is part of the join condition.

Because of the `LEFT JOIN`, when a row of `l` (the left table) does not have a match in `n` (the right table), a row full of `NULL`s is used instead (for the columns of `n`).

The join condition matches all the rows from `l` with the rows from `n` that have the same `id_number` and are *greater* on the `(accepted, register_date)` part. The row of `l` having the biggest value of `(accepted, register_date)` will not have any match in `n`, being completed with `NULL`s.

The `WHERE` clause keeps only the rows having `NULL` in the columns selected from `n`, which means they have the *biggest* value on the `(accepted, register_date)` pair.

Finally, the `SELECT` clause extracts the columns you need from the left table `l` (the columns of `n` are all `NULL` anyway).

Complete the query with other `WHERE` conditions (if you need them) and add the appropriate `ORDER BY` expressions to get the rows in the desired order.

Comment: This did the trick! Shorter than the other one and just in one query. No I will order by the id_number and it will do all i need, thanks. Marked as accepted since it was better than the other answer

Answer (score 1):

**If the item has been accepted at least once, I need the item with the newer register_date but only looking at the accepted of its kind.**

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT id_number,MAX(register_date) FROM mytable WHERE accepted = 1 GROUP BY id_number) accepted
JOIN mytable ON (mytable.id_number = accepted.id_number AND mytable.register_date = accepted.register_date)
```

**If the item hasn't been accepted, then I need the lastest item that has been registered.**

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT id_number
    FROM mytable
    GROUP BY id_number
    HAVING SUM(accepted) = 0
) not_accepted
LEFT JOIN mytable ON (mytable.id_number = not_accepted.id_number)
GROUP BY mytable.id_number
ORDER BY register_date DESC
```

Comment: The first query does not produce the desired results. `ORDER BY` applies after `GROUP BY`, it sorts the groups not the entries inside a group.

Comment: @axiac you are right, I always fall for this.. fixed.

Comment: The first bit of code seems OK. The second bit of code leaves at lot to be deisred.

Comment: This seems to help. I was trying to get all the results on the same query which didn't work