# MySQL: Select latest record if exists, NULL if not

Tags: mysql, sql

Having the following two tables:

Players

```
id | player
-----------
 1 | ABC
 2 | CDE
 3 | FGH
```

Games

```
id | player_id | created_at
-------------------------------------
 1 | 1         | 2019-09-01 15:00:00
 2 | 1         | 2019-09-15 17:00:00
 3 | 2         | 2019-10-01 15:00:00
 4 | 2         | 2019-10-05 18:00:00
 5 | 2         | 2019-10-12 15:00:00
```

How can I select all players and show their latest if they have any, or NULL if they never played a game? Something like this with this example:

```
player_id | created_at
--------------------------------
        1 | 2019-09-15 17:00:00
        2 | 2019-10-12 15:00:00
        3 | NULL
```

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27802817/4265352), [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36956474/4265352), [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29302379/4265352) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28090544/4265352) to similar questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL order by before group by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14770671/mysql-order-by-before-group-by)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try below - use `left join`

```
select p.id, max(created_at)
from Players p left join Games g on p.id=g.player_id
group by p.id
```

Comment: Oh, ok. My mistake was to group by `g.player_id`. Thanks.